# Getting mstest results to display in CruiseControl.Net Build Report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, mstest

I am trying to setup CruiseControl.Net to display results from mstest unit tests (msbuild / Visual Studio 2010) in the build report.  I am merging the results and they do show up properly in the build log, but not in the build report.  I have also tried just dumping some text in the MsTestSummary2008.xsl and that text does show in the build report, so the xsl does seem to be included properly.

Do I need a new/different .xsl for VS2010? Thanks in advance.

ccnet.config:

```
 <publishers>
  <merge>
    <files>
      <file>C:\_Projects\test\code\results\results1.trx</file>
    </files>
  </merge>
  <xmllogger />
  <statistics />
</publishers>
```

dashboard.config:

```
 <buildPlugins>
  <buildReportBuildPlugin>
    <xslFileNames>
      <xslFile>xsl\header.xsl</xslFile>
      <xslFile>xsl\modifications.xsl</xslFile>
      <xslFile>xsl\MsTestSummary2008.xsl</xslFile>
    </xslFileNames>
  </buildReportBuildPlugin>
  <buildLogBuildPlugin />
  <xslReportBuildPlugin description="MSTest Report" actionName="MSTESTReport" xslFileName="xsl\MsTestReport2008.xsl" />
</buildPlugins>
```

Comment: The author of the following article on CodeProject claims that 2010 MsTest report works fine with CCNET's 2008 XSL: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117716/CruiseControl-Net-and-MSTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the modified XSL mentioned in [this thread](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/community/forums/test-studio-express/general-discussions/display-report-automation-test-on-cruise-control.aspx) will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the thread, i was able to solve my issue after reading through.  Turns out I had a pathing issue with the location MSTEST was dumping the results and where i was merging the file from.  I also utilized the modified XSL mentioned in the thread, it had a way slicker output for the unit test results.  Thanks Again!